# How to send and receive data in Magento?

Tags: ajax, magento

How can I send and receive data in Magento and AJAX? When I am sending data using AJAX, its not taking the URL?

Please let me know what is wrong in this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#category").on('change',function(){

        var prize = "<?php echo $spac_name;?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl())->getPath()?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {prize :prize},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#da_ta').html("haha");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any error on your console? Can you post your ajax body ***after initialization of the page**? I want to see generated url.

Comment: You need to do some debugging to find the problem. Too difficult to ell from here.